# Mongoose population

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this Mongoose Schema

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    "name":String,
    "review": [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Reviews'}]
});
```

and the schema of the review is:

```
var ReviewSchema = new Schema({
    "title": String, 
    "user": { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }
});
```

and the schema of the users is:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   "name":String, 
   "surname":String,
});
```

This is the code to get the item:

```
Item.findOne({_id:req.params.idItem})
    .populate('review')
    .exec(function (err, item) {
        console.log(item);
});
```

But this code only populates the reviews, and I want that to populate also the user.

Comment: for a moment I thought you were asking of the animal population haha. have you tried chaining? `Item.findOne({_id:req.params.idItem})
    .populate('review').populate('user')
    .exec(function (err, item) {
        console.log(item);
});`

Comment: I've tried it, but `.populate` it refers only to the attributes of the item, not of review @ManuAntony

Comment: @Lorenzo which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.4.2 @war1oc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Item.findOne({_id:req.params.idItem})
  .populate({ 
     path: 'review',
     populate: {
       path: 'user'
     } 
  })
  .exec(function(err, item) {});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate